# Kruskal Algorithm, exited with code=code=3221225477

Tags: c, kruskals-algorithm

```
#define MAX_VERTICES 10000
#define MAX_EDGES 50000000
#define HEAP_EMPTY(n) (!n)
#define LINE_SIZE  100
#define HEAP_FULL(n) (n == MAX_EDGES-1)


typedef struct {
  int weight;
  int node1;
  int node2;
} element;


element min_heap[MAX_EDGES];
int parent_array[MAX_VERTICES];

element delete_min_heap(int *n) {
  /* delete element with the highest key from the heap */
  int parent, child;
  element item, temp;
  if(HEAP_EMPTY(*n)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The heap is empty");
    exit(1);
  }
  /* save value of the element with the largest key */
  item = min_heap[1];
  /* use the last element in the heap to adjust heap */
  temp = min_heap[(*n)--];
  parent = 1;
  child = 2;
  while(child <= *n) {
    /* find the larger child of the current parent */
    if((child < *n) && (min_heap[child].weight > min_heap[child+1].weight)) child++;
    if(temp.weight <= min_heap[child].weight) break;
    /* move to the next lower level */
    min_heap[parent] = min_heap[child];
    parent = child;
    child *= 2;
  }
  min_heap[parent] = temp;
  return item;
}

void insert_min_heap(element item, int *n) {

  int i;
  if(HEAP_FULL(*n)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The heap is full.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  i = ++(*n);
  while((i != 1) && (item.weight < min_heap[i/2].weight)) {
    min_heap[i] = min_heap[i/2];
    i /= 2;
  }
  min_heap[i] = item;
}

int simpleFind(int i) {
    for( ; parent_array[i] >= 0; i = parent_array[i])
        ;
    return i;
    
}

void weightedUnion(int i, int j) {
    int temp = parent_array[i] + parent_array[j];
    if(parent_array[i] > parent_array[j]) {
        parent_array[i] = j;
        parent_array[j] = temp;
    } else {
        parent_array[j] = i;
        parent_array[i] = temp;
    }
    
}

void main(int argc, char **argv) {  //argc = argument 개수 argv argument list
    
    //if(argc != 2) {
      //printf("No input file is given or Two many input files are given.\n");
      
      //exit(0);
    //}
    clock_t start = clock();
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("input_large.txt", "r"); //replace to argv[1]
    if(fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("The input file does not exist.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    char *command_line;
    char buffer[LINE_SIZE];
    int cost;
    int n_connected;

    
    start = clock();
    FILE *f = fopen("hw3_result.txt", "w+");
    int line_num= 0;
    int num_edges;
    int num_vertices;
    int n_heap = 0;
    
    while (!feof(fp1)) {  //한줄 씩 입력받기
        element edge;
        command_line = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp1);
        if(line_num == 0) {num_vertices = atoi(command_line);}
        else if(line_num == 1) {num_edges = atoi(command_line);}
        else {
            int vertex_from = atoi(strtok(command_line, " "));
            int vertex_to = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
            int weigth = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
            
            edge.node1 = vertex_from;
            edge.node2 = vertex_to;
            edge.weight = weigth;

            insert_min_heap(edge, &n_heap);
        
        }
        line_num++;
  }
  fclose(fp1);
  
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i< num_vertices; i++) { parent_array[i]=-1;}
  element edge = delete_min_heap(&n_heap);

  
  int j = 0;
  cost = 0;
  n_connected =0;
  
  while((n_heap >= 0) && (n_connected != num_vertices)) {
    
    int node1 = edge.node1;
    int node2 = edge.node2;
    if(j == 0)  {
      weightedUnion(node1, node2);
      cost += edge.weight;
      //printf("%d %d %d\n",node1, node2, edge.weight);
      n_connected += 2;
      j++;
    }
    else if ( simpleFind(node1) != simpleFind(node2)) {
      weightedUnion(node1, node2);
      cost += edge.weight;
      //printf("%d %d %d\n",node1, node2, edge.weight);
      n_connected++;
    }
    edge = delete_min_heap(&n_heap);
    printf("%d %d\n", n_connected, n_heap);
  }

  printf("END\n");
  printf("COST%d\n", cost);
  printf("num vertices %d connected %d\n", num_vertices, n_connected);
  if(n_connected < num_vertices) printf("DISCONNECTED\n");
  if(n_connected == num_vertices) printf("CONNECTED\n");
  
  fclose(f);
  
  clock_t end = clock();
  double time_spent = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("output written to hw3_result.txt\n");
  printf("running time :%lf\n", time_spent); 
}
```

I tried to implement Kruskal's Algorithm, but I faced some problems. The format of the input file is like this.

```
7
9
0 1 28
0 5 10
1 2 16
1 6 14
2 3 12  //source vertex destination vertex weight
3 4 22
3 6 18
4 5 25
4 6 24
```

The first line is the number of vertices and the second is number of edges. There is no problem when running small input file, but when the input file is very large, the program is exited with  code=3221225477.
This code is to find where the code is exited

```
while((n_heap >= 0) && (n_connected != num_vertices)) {
    
    int node1 = edge.node1;
    int node2 = edge.node2;
    if(j == 0)  {
      weightedUnion(node1, node2);
      cost += edge.weight;
      //printf("%d %d %d\n",node1, node2, edge.weight);
      n_connected += 2;
      j++;
    }
    else if ( simpleFind(node1) != simpleFind(node2)) {
      weightedUnion(node1, node2);
      cost += edge.weight;
      //printf("%d %d %d\n",node1, node2, edge.weight);
      n_connected++;
    }
    edge = delete_min_heap(&n_heap);
    **printf("%d %d\n", n_connected, n_heap);**  //here
  }
```

The result is like this.

```
...
1657 4998343  //num of connected vertices num of heap's remaining element
1658 4998342
1659 4998341
1660 4998340
1661 4998339
1662
```

After deleting 1661 element in heap, for some reasons, program doesn't work any more.

Comment: 3221225477 is hex C0000005, the code for an access violation. You have `while(child <= *n)` and then `min_heap[child+1]`. Check the array indexing.

Comment: You haven't checked the return value `command_line` from `fgets()` before dereferencing it. Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) You should use the return value from `fgets()` to control the loop.

Comment: there is no wrong after inserting elements and deleting too... Also the exit point is vary according to the heap size

Comment: There is no predicting exactly where an error will happen if the code has undefined behaviour, for example writing outside memory bounds.